# Proper way of emailing - design patterns

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm looking for some advice on how to make proper 'data collector' for email notifications.

In my application, a user can change his address data, preferences, goals, habits, etc. Whenever a user changes any of the above, an email is sent with the things that have changed. 
Mail is sent via :

```
static function sendChangeMail()
```

Where I put information with changes, but at this moment, this function takes too many parameters (7 exactly), and it can be confusing. I want to put all changed elements into one object.

How it should look, I mean, should I make some other 'CollectiongDataMailClass' or maybe some Observer?

I thought about using an Observer, but when a user address is updated, function 'create' is executed. The mail would be sent even after registration of a new user, and I don't want that.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @RamChander  Well, first time I expanded mentioned function with further arguments and it works but I know this is not the right solution. Now I try to make some other class where I put functions to take address data, habits data etc but it looks just like my models so i think it's also not good solution

Comment: The question title is misleading but the answer is probably something like *"look up **dependency injection**"*

Comment: @jakemen your question title is not as per StackOverflow guidelines. you probably share the efforts that you have tried and mentioned the problem/error where you got stuck. Your question is seems to be like a discussion which should be asked on another plateform.

Comment: @ramChander I changed the title of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case of using [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

So you basically need to build the object with your changedData and pass it on to the `sendChangeMail(ChangedSettingsObject $changedSettingsObject)`.

As an example.

DTO object structure:

```php
class changedDataDTO {
    public $address;
    public $preferences;
    public $goals;
    public $habits;
}
```

Building the DTO object:

```php
$changedData = new changedDataDTO;
$changedData->address = 'Germany';
$changedData->preferences = ['setting1' => 'Value 1', 'setting2' => 'Value2'];
// ...

// pass it on to the mail function
..->sendChangeMail($changedData);
```

SendChangeMail function

```php
pubic function sendChangeMail(changedDataDTO $changedDataDTO)
{
    dd($changedDataDTO); // you'll get the whole object here
}
```

This way you need to pass only one parameter to the underlying method.